# Using javamail in android

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to find a simple straightforward way to create a very simple android client; send, receive and just display the emails. Currently I have tried several methods; using an Intent on the default android app does not seem to work in order to get the message contents, so I have used javamail and successfully implement the send function. But the real problem for me is the receive function, I don't quite understand how it works but due to help from this thread :

I managed to create the receive function but I can't see the contents of it and also when I rerun my code it cant access the messages saying that there are not new messages etc. Can someone point me to articles that might be useful? I think that I must read the Javamail Specification but that is not referring to android.

Comment: Try looking at this question and response [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap/2033124#2033124](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap/2033124#2033124)

Comment: Thanks for the link, i had already seen that anyway. However It has many information on sending the emails not receiving them.

Comment: [This page](http://www.zdnetasia.com/receiving-in-javamail-39304762.htm) discusses receiving emails in javamail. However, if you want help with your specific problems then post some code so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: Here is my other question that does have some code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035336/javamail-to-receive-emails-whats-wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i have done both functions. I couldnt see the contents because they are an output stream that need to be converted. When i re-run the program for the 2nd i cant see the messages because a flag was used.