# Javamail to receive emails; whats wrong?

Tags: email, client, jakarta-mail, imap

I am trying to create a very simple (text based for now) email app for receiving emails. So far i have used this code :

http://www.javaer.org/j2ee/3-javamail/8-javamail-connecting-gmail-using-pop3-with-ssl

The problem is that i when i run this code i am able to get the new emails, only for once. For example if i have a new message in inbox the first time i will this code it will show it but then it wont. Also it seems that i cant see the body contents of the emails which is strange. I was told that it should be better to use imap protocol but i am not entirely sure how.

Comment: I have the same problem， Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specified example really starts once and scans folder and exits (and see answer on POP that removes mail). From description you need some loop that periodically checks catalog and extracts new mails. Look at some swing examples in your JDK how to write window-based program with event loop. You can start dedicated thread that once per minute checks POP server catalog

Comment: Ok thanks for your informations. Iam familiar with threads and gui in java. What i dont get is why the body of the email is no displayed even thought i print it. It correctly prints the reference objcect and then some ranbom stuff. I cant seem to find the way to get the textual contents.

Comment: @Stelios, could you place "some ranbom stuff" - may be it is UUCODE of real body?

Comment: @Stelios also pay attention, that `getContent` - returns complicated object that depends on `getContentType` so you need extra efforts to parse it into human readable form. See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/Part.html#getContent() for details

Comment: Thanks, i have done it, i should have created an output stream and print that.

Comment: It seams your answer is not related to the question