# Can't receive gmail repeatly with javamail

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail

Someone asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035336/javamail-to-receive-emails-whats-wrong), but I  think it has not been solved yet.

I doubt the result  is due to google mail server policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace 'username@gmail.com' in the 'Username' or 'Email' field with 'recent:username@gmail.com' . see [Using POP on multiple clients or mobile devices](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/47948?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better if you asked your own question, with your own details about what you're doing, what you've tried, what the results were, etc.

While you're working on that, see the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) entries related to GMail and debugging.